# How to insert pipes into (edited) FASTA sequence headers to restore original format?

Tags: bash, unix, awk

I have a file that contains (edited) sequence headers in the first column, e.g.:

```
gi399604265gbAKZP01155332.1     10      255     L1-1_STu        1       -
gi399594056gbCM001217.1     19      203     L1-4_VC 1       -
gi399591950gbKE558403.1     1       185     L1-4_VC 1       +
gi399591329gbAKZP01168266.1     4       285     L1-1_STu        1       +
gi399589894gbAKZP01169701.1     28      502     L1-3_NV 1       +
```

I'd like to convert these seq headers back to their original format, which 
includes pipes, e.g. desired output:

```
gi|399604265|gb|AKZP01155332.1|     10      255     L1-1_STu        1       -
gi|399594056|gb|CM001217.1|     19      203     L1-4_VC 1       -
gi|399591950|gb|KE558403.1|     1       185     L1-4_VC 1       +
gi|399591329|gb|AKZP01168266.1|     4       285     L1-1_STu        1       +
gi|399589894|gb|AKZP01169701.1|     28      502     L1-3_NV 1       +
```

The pipes always occur after the first "gi", before "gb", after "gb", and at the end. Is there an easy way to automate this for all my files? (some of which are very large!)

Many thanks for any suggestions :)

Answer (score 0):

A simple one liner will do:

```
perl -pe 's/(gi)(\d+)(gb)(\S+)/$1|$2|$3|$4|/' file.txt
```

Output

```
gi|399604265|gb|AKZP01155332.1|     10      255     L1-1_STu        1       -
gi|399594056|gb|CM001217.1|     19      203     L1-4_VC 1       -
gi|399591950|gb|KE558403.1|     1       185     L1-4_VC 1       +
gi|399591329|gb|AKZP01168266.1|     4       285     L1-1_STu        1       +
gi|399589894|gb|AKZP01169701.1|     28      502     L1-3_NV 1       +
```

Comment: Thank you! Works like a charm :)